# Noun for for u-shaped bend on electrical component's pin (wire) to aid in placement (Beading / Ribbing / Crimp)?

Tags: nouns, technical, shapes

I'm trying to find the correct noun for a u-shaped bend in an electrical component's pin.
Is there a generic technical term that may usually refer to a deformation to reinforce e.g. an (angle) bracket made of sheet metal, where the 90° bend has been given a groove?

If you provided a few sentences using potential synonyms I would be grateful.

Comment: Is it like a score or scoring?  Do you have a picture?  I take it you aren't describing resistors/capacitors/LEDs.

Comment: Yes, give more detail. Are you describing a connector pin, that would mate with a socket? Fluting is good, but maybe obscure to a techie. "A stiffening bend is used to keep the otherwise flat metal pin rigid for insertion."

Comment: It seems like what the title is asking about is completely different to what the description is asking for.  The "J-Hook" on the end of a wire, used to "hook" around a connection post that helps hold it in place while being soldered or fastened with a nut, is completely different that the ribbing or fluting that provides extra rigidity in thin sheet metal parts.

Comment: Jim has it right, the confusion is caused by the German word "Sicke", which seems to be used for both, the reinforcing bend e.g. in an angle bracket, and the formed leads of an electronics component. jwpat chose to ignore my description and answered the question in the "title" directly, giving me the information and an example that helps very much. Thank you all for contributing.

Answer (score 3):

For component leads, the rather generic terms *lead forming* and *formed leads* are often used.  As an example, some [thermistors](http://www.redfishsensors.com/index.php/temperature/redfish-thermistors/radial-leaded-thermistor/rsbr-10k-bare-formed-leads.html) are supplied with an offset jog referred to as *formed leads*.  A second jog could give the U-shape you mention, which I think is somewhat as in first photo below. The other picture shows Excelta *lead forming pliers*.
[image: assembly with U's]   [image: Lead forming pliers]

*Edit:* Note that besides the *dog leg* bends mentioned in my answer two weeks ago, some related terms include  *inclined gull-wing, spider J-bend*, and *spider gull-wing* [lead designs](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/105132) for surface mount components, and *omega bends* and *camel humps* for surface mount [quad packs and flat packs](https://web.archive.org/web/20120510105628/http://www.fancort.com:80/smt/specs.html) as in picture below.
[image: camel hump]

Comment: Is this for reinforcing the bend (what the OP is looking for)? Also, is this the same as 'crimping'?

Comment: No, *lead forming* mainly is relevant to the "u-shaped bend on electrical component's pin (wire) to aid in placement" portion of the question.  Leads may be formed to fit required hole spacing, or to avoid dropping too far into a hole, or to provide some flex; but not reinforcing as far as I know.  Also, crimping is different than forming; it is *eg* crushing a connector-pin's shell around a wire of a cable to make a tight connection.

Comment: Looks lake something out of Terry Pratchett.

Answer (score 0):

Technically I think its dog leg, but very often referred to as a knee, which can be any forming that shows the depth of insertion of the lead to a hole or pad. Could also be referred to as a crimp *in* the leg.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second question,  The cross section channel around a corner is normally called a rib.

[image]